# Set Field Value during Email Sales Order process under Slaes Order Entry Actions

Tags: acumatica

I created a new field, UsrAcknowledged, boolean, checkbox, and placed it on the SOLine details grid. I want every line on the details grid to be checked when the Email Sales Order/Quote process is run under Actions for SOOrder.  My code is as follows under the SOOrderEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension

```
  public CRActivityList<SOOrder>    Activity;
  public PXAction<SOOrder> notification;
  [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Notifications", Visible = false)]
  [PXButton(ImageKey = PX.Web.UI.Sprite.Main.DataEntryF)]
  protected virtual IEnumerable Notification(PXAdapter adapter,
  [PXString]
  string notificationCD
  )
  {
    foreach (SOOrder order in adapter.Get<SOOrder>())
    {

      var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      parameters["SOOrder.OrderType"] = order.OrderType;
      parameters["SOOrder.OrderNbr"] = order.OrderNbr;
     Activity.SendNotification(ARNotificationSource.Customer,          notificationCD, order.BranchID, parameters);
//order.OrderDesc = "Desc";
  foreach (SOLine line in PXSelect<SOLine>.Select(Base, order.OrderNbr))
  {
       SOLineExt rowExt = line.GetExtension<SOLineExt>();
       rowExt.UsrAcknowledged = true;
           line.OrderQty = 5;
  }
  yield return order;
}
```

}

//order.Desc = "Desc" was an initial simple test just to see if my code was achieving the desired results and the proder desciption was changed as planned.
My code compiles and the email process runs as planned with a green check for successful, but neither the Acknowledged check box nor the Order Quantity are changed.  I don't really care about the ord qty, it was just another test.
Any suggestions for what I can change to update the Acknowledged checkbox to checked during the Email Sales Order/Quote under Actions on the SO Order Entry screen would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say you need to call Base.Transactions.Update(line) after you update your row values inside your foreach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but after adding Base.Transactions.Update(line) the email process took over a minute to run and produced the error SalesAcctID may not be empty

Comment: What happens if you move your foreach before the send notification call? same lag? what happens when you update your sales order in the UI? do you get the same error message on SalesAcctID?

Comment: When I update the order manually by checking the Acknowledged box and saving it works as expected.  Moving the send notification to after the foreach line produced the sames results as above

Comment: Not sure then on this one. I know I have seen that error in the past related to an extension issue on sales order. What version of Acumatica are you running? (Ex: 5.30.2562)

Comment: Although it might not help with the Send notification code taking a while. curios if you comment out the send notification line does it save update the value without error?

Comment: 6.00.1263
commenting out the send notification did not change the results, same time, same error

Comment: I had to modify my PXSelect in the foreach statement.
    foreach (SOLine line in PXSelect<SOLine, Where<SOLine.orderNbr,   Equal<Required<SOLine.orderNbr>>>>.Select(Base, order.OrderNbr))
After I did this
    Base.Transactions.Update(line);
worked.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Ah yea i didn't even see you were missing the where statement. This might cause your hang as you searched for all sales lines in your database. Glad you got it working.